# Best way to convert UIF to ISO

Tags: windows, conversion, iso-image

I have a UIF file and would like to convert it to an ISO file.  What is the best way to do this on Windows.

Answer (score 7):

Do a google for uif2iso - that's the one I used under Windows last time I found a CD image in this format.  You can find it [here](http://download.softpedia.com/dl/f28ec61b3fb191c4bd06100ee49fb749/490ce984/100094290/software/file_management/uif2iso.zip).

I wish people would just stick to the one format - I tire of converting NRG/ISO/UIF/CUE files.

Answer (score 1):

I use this [uif to iso converter - AnyToISO](http://www.crystalidea.com/anytoiso), it also converts many others formats to ISO. Also works on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a way to convert uif to iso in windows, and downloaded AnytoIso as per Niegel suggestion. I was disappointed because it is a freeware program, and wants you to pay $23 dollars. Boo.

I googled uif2iso and found another tutorial that shows how to convert a [uif to iso format](http://wesleybailey.com/articles/uif-to-iso-converter) in windows and linux for free. For anyone else that is looking for a truly free program that gets the job done, check it out, worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try UIF2ISO: http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/UIF2ISO-Download-94290.html I'm trying it right now on a 2.6GB .uif. Seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are downloading an ISO/UIF that means you probably have some sharing programs and probably a few utilites that generally go with that.

Step 1. Mount the UIF file on a Virtual Drive in MagicDisc

Step 2. Open MagicISO and select Make ISO from CD/DVD Rom

Step 3. Select MagicISO Virtual DVD-ROM from first drop down.

Step 4. Type in the name you want in the Blank.

Step 5. Select Output format. Standard ISO image file (.iso) from second drop-down.

Step 6. Press ok and Wait.

Your new ISO will be on your desktop by default.

Comment: Why resurrect this question with this answer? This isn't useful and assumes things it doesn't need to.